# How to force backup through Time Machine in terminal

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine

I am trying to force **Time Machine** to do backup with terminal, to backup one virtual machine while it is saved and stopped, but till now I am unable to do that,

```
tmutil startbackup --auto
```

and then, to check if that backup has been made,

```
tmutil listbackup
```

but there is no new entry in the list after.

Comment: When I run 'tmutil listbackup' I get an 'unrecognized verb' message?  Can you help?

Comment: I found problem. Should be listbackups   Need to make that plural.  Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check Time Machine GUI I notice that it was working as expected, but it was tacking a while because after backup there was also a cleaning part. There is no need for higher privileges to use this command.